# haml adding styles to form elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, styling, form-for

Couldn't seem to find the answer to this question - what is the haml syntax for adding styles or a class styling to elements within a rails form_for?

The code I am dealing with is

```
.row.form
.threecol
.sevencol
    = form_for @article do |a|
      %h3= a.label "title"
      =    a.text_field :title 
      %h3= a.label "description"
      =    a.text_area :description
      %h3= a.label "body"
      =    a.text_area :body
      %br/
      =  a.submit "Post Article"
 .twocol.last
```

I am wanting to add a style to the text area description element.
I have tried (where new_desc is the class styling)

```
= a.text_area.new_desc :description
```

and

```
= a.text_area { :style ... } :description
```

but both failed to compile.
Can anyone help with this (hopefully trivial) problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

text_area is a method that takes (object, method, and options) (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area)

When you have it attached to a form object, you withhold the object, so it becomes text_area(method, options={})

```
= a.text_area :description, class: "description"
```

or

```
= a.text_area :description, class: "description", style: "font-size: 45"
```

Comment: Great - thanks for that. Gradually coming to understand the syntax.

Comment: Seems for me that the additions need to be formatted as a rails hash? Might be helpful to correct for anyone else reading this confused by the syntax.